# How to get checked ToolStripMenuItem?

Tags: c#, menu, menuitem, toolstrip, menustrip

I am using a `MenuStrip` with two main `ToolStripMenuItems`, each one of those has its "dropdown" with more ToolStripMenuItems that have the `CheckOnClick` property set to true.

Now I am trying to retrieve the selected item, I know `bool ToolStripMenuItem.Checked` exists, but how can I use a loop to get the `ToolStripMenuItems` from each main `ToolStripMenuItem` and then check which one has .Cheked is == true?

Or is there a better way to retrieve the checked `ToolStripMenuItem`?

Comment: Simply iterate the Items property with foreach.  Not at all clear why you have a problem doing this.

Comment: I didn't know what to loop, ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Assume you are using Linq, here is what you can do:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in this.menuStrip1.Items.Cast<ToolStripMenuItem>())
        {
            GetCheckMenuItemText(item);
        }
    }

    private void GetCheckMenuItemText(ToolStripMenuItem item)
    {
        if (item.HasDropDownItems)
        {
            foreach (var subItem in item.DropDownItems.Cast<ToolStripMenuItem>())
            {
                GetCheckMenuItemText(subItem);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (item.CheckOnClick)
                Debug.WriteLine(item.Text);
        }
    }
```